# AngularJS + Spring security remember me feature

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I'm doing application which is build on spring boot + Angularjs
Authentication I did according to this blog post: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/
So I got basic user/password or OAuth2 enabled

I would like to add Remmeber me functionality to it. I have AuthService

```
AuthService.authenticate = function (credentials, callback) {
    var headers = credentials ? {
        authorization: "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};

    $http.get('api/user/', {headers: headers}, {timeout: 5000}).then(
        function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            if (data.id) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.principal = data;
                $translate.use($rootScope.principal.language);
                $location.search('lang', $rootScope.principal.language);
                AvatarService.getUserAvatar($rootScope.principal);
                $log.debug("[DEBUG] User logged in " + $rootScope.principal.id);
            } else {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            }
            callback && callback();
        },
        function () {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            callback && callback();
        });
};
```

And in login controller I got it handled with :

```
$scope.credentials = {};
//LOGIN
$scope.login = function () {
    AuthService.authenticate($scope.credentials, function () {
        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
            $location.path("/");
            AlertService.clearAlerts();
        } else {
            $location.path("/login");
            AlertService.addError('user.login.failed');
        }
    });
};
```

On Spring security I got it set as usually I was setting it, ( part of config)

```
            ....
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/#/login")
                .and().rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .key("remember-me-key")
            .and().addFilterBefore(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf()
            ....
```

but my guess is it expect post call with remember-me and not basic auth

How can it be tweaked to be able to use remember me ? 
Can I just execute call via post to login with j_username j_password and remember-me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can config spring boot server to issue an auth token back to the client. In the client side(Angular), save the token somewhere(local storage/cookie). Then you can check the existence of the token when app first loads. 
JWT tokens are really good when dealing with web client authentications.

For example, if I have this block of code in my security configuration file.

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/login.html", "/home.html").permitAll()
.anyRequest()
.authenticated().and()
.formLogin()
    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
```

I can easily implement the `authenticationSuccessHandler` and issue an auth token, or an auth cookie, or both back to the user upon successful logins.

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

... bla bla bla

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication ) throws IOException, ServletException {
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();

    String jws = tokenHelper.generateToken( user.getUsername() );

    // cookie in response
    Cookie authCookie = new Cookie( TOKEN_COOKIE, ( jws ) );
    authCookie.setPath( "/" );
    authCookie.setHttpOnly( true );
    authCookie.setMaxAge( EXPIRES_IN );
    response.addCookie( authCookie );
    // token in response
    UserTokenState userTokenState = new UserTokenState(jws, EXPIRES_IN);
    String jwtResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString( userTokenState );
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write( jwtResponse );
}
```

}

More detail can be found in [springboot-jwt-starter](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter). This is a starter-kit project using spring boot and AngularJS.

The [The Login Page: Angular JS and Spring Security Part II](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) series is a very good reading material if you want to implement Spring boot security with Angular.

Comment: The [The Login Page: Angular JS and Spring Security Part II](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) is exacly based on what I did my application so that part I got covered. Will check solution with auth token  soon

Comment: springboot-jwt-starter is based on "The Login Page: Angular JS and Spring Security Part II" but instead of using a session, it uses JWT(JSON web token). Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your github code I was able to adapt my app so it would use token and hold it for 1 week . Works for normal and Oath logins

Comment: Sweet, I'm glad to hear my code helped. Would you mind supporting the github code by giving it a star?

Comment: Sure thing :)
One remark: On TokenFilter there is query to DB on every request which is not good performance wise. 
In my app I added sessions ( removed the stateless from config ), and get token value and account from DB only if
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()  or instanceof AnonAuthentication. As additional benefit , auth have current account and when calling whoami , it can be returned dirrectly. Also in my app I store whole principal in angular $rootContext.principal. So that all info like mail , id or avatar id can be read without extra query to backend

Comment: Stakoverflow cut my answer
The token check and account from database is checked when 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null or 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() instanceof AnonAuthentication

Comment: Nice, but we should try to avoid using the server session. There is a different approach if you don't want to call the db on every request. You can save some more information about the user in the token, like user_role and then if the token passes the parse state, put that user info in the SecurityContextHolder. The plus side of this approach is we are still using a STATELESS server. The downside is this will rise some security issue as saving sensitive information on the client side is never a good idea. Is a trade off.

Comment: By setting a shorter TTL for the access token and use a long live refresh token can resolve the security issue. The GitHub JWT repo is only meant for getting you started. You can tune it as much as you want. :^). On a side note, I thinking of adding the refresh token implementation to the project in the future, when I have free time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing the Spring + Angular2 application. In my case, the backend returns 2 tokens (access token and refresh token). After that I add 'Authorization' to the title to each request: 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring remember-me services with Angular and basic auth, you must send the remember-me parameter with the post.

Here is an example with Angular2:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {CSRF_URL, LOGIN_URL, LOGOUT_URL} from "./auth.constant";

export interface RespAccess {
  email?: String;
  name: string;
  permissions: [string];
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(username: string, password: string, rememberme: boolean): Observable<RespAccess> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
    headers = headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // to suppress 401 browser popup

    const params = new HttpParams().append('remember-me', (rememberme ? 'true' : 'false' ));
    return this.http.post<RespAccess>(LOGIN_URL,'', {headers, params});
  }

  logout() : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(LOGOUT_URL, '');
  }

  getCSRFToken() {
    this.http.get<any>(CSRF_URL) // /api/auth/csrf
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

If you are using CSRF protection, you must obtain the CSRF token prior to login. You can do that simply accessing a unsecured url that returns the token, here is the method in a controller in Spring server side:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/auth/csrf")
public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token) {
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Carlos Cuesta, even if remember me param is false also creating cookie.